# Multiple NUnit tests reading in a long stream

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, stream, nunit

I'm new into unit testing and I came across a problem.
My application is reading in a file with lots of data frames and the tests are supposed to validate how my program deals with them.
There are different kind of errors that can occur reading these frames, and they can happen anywhere in the file. Reading through the entire file can take 2 seconds and the amount of tests can become massive.

Which means that reading in the file just once and testing it for all errors in that one run would be the most effective way. However, that is against the common test pattern I see recommended everywhere. Common test pattern recommend to have 1 test method per test, but this would mean if I want to test 10 things I have to read through the entire file 10 times. Especially when they get more and more this would be very ineffective through. There are no shortcuts possible, all these tests require to read the whole file.

I know the types of errors that can occur, I just do not know where and if it's there before the test starts.

My current "dirty" solution is to add all errors to a list and output that list later with an assert.fail, but I've read multiple times that this is indeed a very dirty solution.

One idea I had was that one thread reads through the file and "feeds" all test methods with the next record, and waits for them until it proceeds. However, I do not believe it is possible to pull this off.

Any idea on how to make this clean and effective? Or should I just take the cheat and add them all to a list like I'm doing right now? Most internet examples are too much perfect world examples and it's hard to find solutions for things like this.

Edit: I'm aware it's possible to execute tests in Parallel, but wouldn't this just delay the inevitable bottle neck?

Edit2:

This is the design of the code.

```
    private List<TestError> errors;
    private Session session;
    private MemoryStream mStr;

    private void Init()
    {
        errors = new List<TestError>();
        session = new Session();
        var test = NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.Test;

        mStr = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory + "\\Files\\" + test.ClassName.Split('.')[2] + "_" + test.MethodName + ".bin"));

        session.StartRawDataRecording(mStr,
            true, true);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Test1()
    {

        Init();
        var recorder = session.Recorder as RawDataRecorder;

        while (!recorder.IsCancelled)
        {
            await recorder.ManualLoopTick();

            if({condition1})
            errors.Add(new TestError("condition1", "condition1 occured"));

            if({condition2})
            errors.Add(new TestError("condition2", "condition2 occured"));          
        }

        if(errors.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.AppendLine("Run Errors:");
            for (int i = 0; i < errors.Count;++i)
            {
                var err = errors[i];
                b.AppendLine(String.Format("Error: {0}, Message: {1}",err.Error,err.Message));
                b.AppendLine("Stacktrace: " + err.StackTrace);
                b.AppendLine();
            }

            Assert.Fail(b.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Please, share your code and what have you tried

Comment: Added the code. This is the solution I'm using right now.